# How to sort my dictionary using this condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

How to sort my dictionary using this condition in python.

I have a Nested Dictionary which is describe below.

```
my_dict={
         "Moli": {"Price": 226, "Quantity": 300, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 36},
         "Anna": {"Price": 530, "Quantity": 154, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 26},
         "Bob": {"Price": 250, "Quantity": 100, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 46},
         "Annie": {"Price": 656, "Quantity": 96, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 55},
         "Calley": {"Price": 546, "Quantity": 76, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 35}
        }
```

I want to apply a condition on this nested dictionary. The condition is_

> *Sort the items where ("PreOrder"== "Yes" or "PostOrder"== "Yes") and show those item in descending order using "Quantity" value*

Something like this.

```
my_dict2 = {("PreOrder"== "Yes" or "PostOrder"== "Yes") i[0]: i[1] for i in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["Quantity"], reverse=True)}
```

I know it's a wrong code.

expected output_

```
my_dict2={
         "Moli": {"Price": 226, "Quantity": 300, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 36},
         "Anna": {"Price": 530, "Quantity": 154, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 26},
         "Annie": {"Price": 656, "Quantity": 96, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 55},
         "Calley": {"Price": 546, "Quantity": 76, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 35}
         }
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: that first condition is for filtering, not sorting. Do you only want the items with `"PreOrder"== "Yes" or "PostOrder"== "Yes"`?

Comment: Why is the key `Bob` missing from your expected output?

Comment: Because Bob's ("PreOrder"== "Yes" or "PostOrder"== "Yes") this condition is false. "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "No"

Comment: and yes first check the condition then sorting in descending order using "Quantity" value

Comment: Can I write the code like this filtered = {i[0]: i[1] for i in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["Quantity"], reverse=True) if i[1]["True" not in my_dict[(list(my_dict.keys())[0])].values()]}

Answer (score 2):

This involves multiple steps as you describe. First, we need a dict with only the items that we want. This filters the dict.

```
filtered = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v['PreOrder'] == 'Yes' or v['PostOrder'] == 'Yes'}
```

Then you want to show the items in *order*. This implies a list, not a dictionary. So we'll make one with tuples from the original dict.

```
items = [(k, v) for k, v in filtered.items()]
```

Finally, we need to sort the items. As you've written already, `sort` accepts any arbitrary sorting method, so we can pass in a lambda function for that.

```
ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda i: i[1]['Quantity'], reversed=True)
```

In general, it is very helpful to think about your problems in minimal steps.

Comment: you can do `sorted(filtered.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['Quantity'])` btw

Comment: @Chase Good point! I would emphasize the need to understand the meaning of every step, but once you are comfortable, these kinds of shortcuts can be made.

Comment: Also, since, if i'm correct, version 3.6, dicts are sorted, so ending up with a dict instead of list is possible.

Comment: But sir I getting output like this_

Comment: @go2nirvana True, but I'm personally still uncomfortable with assuming it, because the data structure isn't built for that. For example when switching to other languages it would be easier to make the transition with the same concepts, not relying on an ordered dict.

Comment: my_dict2={
         "Moli": {"Price": 226, "Quantity": 300, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 36},
         "Anna": {"Price": 530, "Quantity": 154, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 26},
         "Annie": {"Price": 656, "Quantity": 96, "PreOrder": "Yes", "PostOrder": "No", "Dif": 55},
         "Calley": {"Price": 546, "Quantity": 76, "PreOrder": "No", "PostOrder": "Yes", "Dif": 35}
         }

Comment: Can I write the code like this filtered = {i[0]: i[1] for i in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["Quantity"], reverse=True) if i[1]["True" not in my_dict[(list(my_dict.keys())[0])].values()]}

Comment: @ammely Do you mean the reverse? My bad, I'll include it in the answer. With regards your other question, I don't really know what you mean. It could be better to ask another question for that. Also, tip: backticks for formatting `code`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using [`pandas`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/index.htm) library:

**This saves a lot of lines of code and also reduces a lot of complexity.**

Install pandas:

`pip install pandas`

Then, create a dataframe from `my_dict`:

```
In [229]: import pandas as pd

In [230]: df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

In [235]: df1 = df.T

In [244]: my_dict2 = df1[df1.PreOrder.eq('Yes') | df1.PostOrder.eq('Yes')].sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending=False).T.to_dict()

In [245]: my_dict2
Out[245]: 
{'Moli': {'Price': 226,
  'Quantity': 300,
  'PreOrder': 'Yes',
  'PostOrder': 'No',
  'Dif': 36},
 'Anna': {'Price': 530,
  'Quantity': 154,
  'PreOrder': 'No',
  'PostOrder': 'Yes',
  'Dif': 26},
 'Annie': {'Price': 656,
  'Quantity': 96,
  'PreOrder': 'Yes',
  'PostOrder': 'No',
  'Dif': 55},
 'Calley': {'Price': 546,
  'Quantity': 76,
  'PreOrder': 'No',
  'PostOrder': 'Yes',
  'Dif': 35}}
```

Comment: @ammely Please check my answer as well.